# How to resolve this issue to display markers on google maps?

Tags: php, google-maps, sqlite

I am working to display the markers on my website.For this purpose i am getting the data from sqlite3 database. Can you correct me where i am doing wrong?

I am getting this error in wamp server:
error on line 1 at column 3: xmlParsePI : no target name

This is my code:

**maps.php:**

```
    <?php
   require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

    // Start XML file, create parent node
    $doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");  
    $node = $doc->createElement ("marker");
    $parnode = $doc->appendChild($node);

  // Opens a connection to a MySQL server

    class MyDB extends SQLite3   
    {
       function __construct()
     {
      $this->open('mytrip.db');

      }
       }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
       echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
     } else {

       }
     // Set the active MySQL database


       // Select all the rows in the markers table
       $query = "SELECT * FROM marker ";
       $resultt = $db->query($query);

       //if (!$result) {
      //  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
         //}

     header("Content-type: text/xml");

   // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
   while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    // Add to XML document node
    $node = $doc->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

     $newnode->set_attribute("city_id", $row['id']);
     $newnode->set_attribute("name", $row['name']);
     // $newnode->set_attribute("address", $row['address']);
      $newnode->set_attribute("latitude", $row['latitude']);
      $newnode->set_attribute("longitude", $row['longitude']);
      $newnode->set_attribute("type", $row['type']);
      }

     $xmlfile = $doc->dump_mem();
    echo $xmlfile;

     ?>
```

**phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php**

```
   <?
    $username="username";
    $password="password";
    $database="username-databaseName"
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked javascript errors ? Are there any?

Comment: No when i remove one error the other error occurs :( kindly help please

Comment: try using `echo $doc->saveXML();`  instead of doing dump_mem() then echo thats how I do it and its fine.  Use firebug/built in browser debug tools to make sure you're getting xml back from your php page then after that its down to ajax issues with parsing the returned xml your code is almost identical to mine apart from your xml output side of things and mines worked fine for 6 years now.

Comment: @Dave it still gives me the same error. Actually i am new to google maps this is my second code.

Comment: This is how I do it https://gist.github.com/hinch/dfbec483e5d65a58fb0411e944787957